# Swap fields inside an Oracle record using couple separator * and elements separator |

Tags: oracle, plsql

In an Oracle table, I have record with COUPLES (string,number) so separated:

```
Abc|3456*Def|7890*Ghi|9430*Jkl|3534
```

In the previous example, the couples are:

```
(Abc,3456)
(Def,7890)
(Ghi,9430)
(Jkl,3534)
```

I would like to modify each record swapping the order of every couple (first the number, then the string):

```
3456|Abc*7890|Def*9430|Ghi*3534|Jkl
```

The separator of the two elements of a couple is pipe (|).
The SEPARATOR BETWEEN COUPLES is asterisk (*).

How can I achieve my objective to swap the order of every couple?

Thank you in advance for your kind cooperation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using regular expressions...now you've got two problems:

```
select 
  cola, 
  regexp_replace(cola, '([^*|]*)\|([^*|]*)(\*|$)','\2|\1\3') as swapped_col
from (
  select '3456|Abc*7890|Def*9430|Ghi*3534|Jkl' cola from dual
)
```

Basically the regex is saying search for everything that isn't a | or a * until you find |, then find everything that isn't a | or * until you find a * or then end of the string. Then swap the two bits and terminate it with the character you found as the final separator (either * or EOL). The bits that are swapped are grouped by the round brackets then in the replace string the numbers denote which is placed where... so the contents of the second set of brackets is put first, then a vertical bar, then the first set of brackets, then the third.

By default, REGEXP_REPLACE will replace every occurrence that it finds of the pattern and replace it

Comment: The regexp_replace does not swap when the strings end with DOT (.).  How can I fix this?!  I have found a WORKAROUND by replacing '.' with 'AEIOU', then using REGEXP_REPLACE, and then by replacing 'AEIOU' with '.' again.  But how can I do it with REGEXP_REPLACE ?

Comment: Just remove the dot (.) from the two sets of square brackets and replace it with an asterisk `[^*|]*`. Sorry, that shouldn't have been there. The square bracket pieces say that it should search for everything except a `|` or a `*`, which are your delimiters. I'll changed the answer